# AsyncTask is still not getting images from rss

Tags: android, image, android-asynctask, rss

With `Android Studio` I am trying to display the images of the `feed` but until now I didn't manage to do that and I haven't found the solution yet. Can you help me please?
That's my `Handler`:

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

final int state_unknown = 0;
final int state_title = 1;
final int state_description = 2;
final int state_link = 3;
final int state_pubdate = 4;
int currentState = state_unknown;
ImageView imm;

RSSFeed feed;
RSSItem item;

boolean itemFound = false;

RSSHandler(){
}

RSSFeed getFeed(){
    return feed;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    feed = new RSSFeed();
    item = new RSSItem();

}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        itemFound = true;
        item = new RSSItem();
        currentState = state_unknown;
    }
    if ("enclosure".equals(qName)) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++)
            if (attributes.getQName(i).equals("url")) ;
        String url = attributes.getValue(i);
        Log.d("mylog", "url= " + url);

        DownloadImagesTask downloadImages = new DownloadImagesTask(imm);
        downloadImages.execute(url);
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
        currentState = state_title;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
        currentState = state_description;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
        currentState = state_link;
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")){
        currentState = state_pubdate;
    }
    else{
        currentState = state_unknown;
    }

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        feed.addItem(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);

    if (itemFound==true){
 // "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_title:
                item.setTitle(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_description:
                item.setDescription(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_link:
                item.setLink(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else{
 // not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
        switch(currentState){
            case state_title:
                feed.setTitle(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_description:
                feed.setDescription(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_link:
                feed.setLink(strCharacters);
                break;
            case state_pubdate:
                feed.setPubdate(strCharacters);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    currentState = state_unknown;
}
```

this my `AsyncTask` class:

```
public class DownloadImagesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

ImageView imageView = null;
String log = null;

public DownloadImagesTask(ImageView imageView){
    this.imageView = imageView;
}


@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... Urls) {
    return download_Image(Urls[0]);
}

private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

    Bitmap bmp =null;
    try{
        URL ulrn = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)ulrn.openConnection();
        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        if (null != bmp)
            return bmp;

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(log, "url= " + url);
    }
    return bmp;}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

and finally my `CustomListView`:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<RSSItem> web;
    private String url;
    private AssetManager assets;



    public CustomList(Activity context, List<RSSItem> web) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, web);
        this.context = context;
        this.web = web;
        this.url = url;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);


        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "BPreplay.otf");


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        final TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        txtTitle.setText(web.get(position).getTitle());
        txtTitle.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        final TextView txtTitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
        txtTitle2.setText(web.get(position).getDescription() + "...");
        txtTitle2.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        TextView txtTitle3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.pub);
        txtTitle3.setText(web.get(position).getPubdate());
        txtTitle3.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        final TextView txtTitle4 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.linke);
        txtTitle4.setText("vai all'articolo completo -->  " + web.get(position).getLink());
        txtTitle4.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        Button btn = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Leggi " +"''" + txtTitle.getText().toString()
                        + ": " + txtTitle2.getText().toString()
                        + txtTitle4.getText().toString() + "''  " + "Condiviso da Active News");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, rowView.getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title)));
            }
        });
        ImageView img = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.immagine_feed);
        DownloadImagesTask downloadImages = new DownloadImagesTask(img);
        downloadImages.execute(url);
        return rowView;

    }
```

Could you help me please? I really need help with this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Volley with ImageLoader, check this out [Volley Tutorial](http://cypressnorth.com/mobile-application-development/setting-android-google-volley-imageloader-networkimageview/). Thats a very good solution for showing images downloaded from url. If it is already downloaded/cached, it will get it from cache, instead downloading it again.

Comment: I don't need to show only an image. I need to show every single image of each article

Comment: Your using getView(...), that means your showing one image per listitem. You have to use in your R.layout.list_item NetworkImageView and in getView you have to pass Volley the Url with the imageloader. Most apps use this technique to show images in listviews.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, anyway I wanted to know what's wrong with this code that don't show the images.

Comment: Problem is, that ur code does not show an image is, that downloading for showing an image each time costs to much time. When u cache it, it looks if that image was downloaded before and gets it from device, instead downloading it. Specially when u scroll quickly, the asyntask will still doing its job, but the imageview is gone.

Comment: What it the simplest one? I need to do it fastly cause I have to go ahead with my app! I'm not very expert with importing other libraries

Comment: Use the code improvement of @Michal and use Volley with imageloader. That is the simplest one.

Comment: Do you have a feedback for us ?

Answer (score 0):

Yours DownloadImageTask is fine although you referencing ImageView from it that can no longer exist when task completes. When decoding bitmap you should check decoding options to minimize memory usage, like http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Also you are not recycling views during getView() on your adapter, that slows down scrolling in listView. As @Luser_k pointed out, check libraries like Volley or Picasso, which manages image download, correct displaying and caching for you. Very easy to use them.

Example:

Check that it recycles views, so inflating view from xml resource is done very few times (basically for nubmer of listItems that can fit into window). If you scroll back or scroll very fast it will reuse that view only with different underlaying data. You dont need to save reference to Context, adapter also has it. Drop asynctask and use libraries like in my example Picasso. Also check for null's on RssItem.getUrl() before loading image. Same adapter may look something like this. I didnt test it though.

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final List<RSSItem> data;
    private AssetManager assets;
    Typeface myTypeface;

    private final class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
        ImageView imageView;
        Button btn;
    }



    public CustomList(Context context, List<RSSItem> data) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, data);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.myTypeface  = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "BPreplay.otf");
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final RssItem item = getItem(position);

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txt1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
            holder.txt1.setTypeface(myTypeface);

            holder.txt2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item2);
            holder.txt2.setTypeface(myTypeface);

            holder.txt3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pub);
            holder.txt3.setTypeface(myTypeface);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.immagine_feed);

            holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);

            holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "extra text from holder.txt1,2 etc.");
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, convertView.getResources().getText(R.string.chooser_title)));
                }
            });

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }


        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.txt1.setText("some text");
        holder.txt2.setText("something else");
        holder.txt3.setText("another text from current item");

        Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(item.getUrl())
                .resizeDimen(80, 80)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.some_placeholder_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.some_placeholder_image)
                .into(holder.imageView);


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: maybe it's too much to ask but could you show me how to change my code adapted to those libraries?